# Is it possible to check if an image stored in an NSimage object is grayscale?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsimage

Is there a simple method for checking if an NSImage Object contains a grayscale image?

What I am trying to do is count the number of colour and black and white pages within a pdf. As far as I can tell the only real solution to this is to render the pdf pages as images and then work from there. I didn't want to have to check every pixel if possible but so far that's all I can come up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `NSImage`'s `-representations` (which returns an array of `NSImageRep` instances) and query the returned `NSImageRep`s for these details.

Primary `NSImageRep` and `CGImage` details of interest include:

- assigned colorspace
- the number of components from the image's bitmap info, bits per component, and bits per pixel.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I've had a look at what you have suggested but all return the same value (when the images are created from the same pdf) regardless of the colours present. I may be missing something, it happens a lot.